# Hide "security warning message" in Java Control Panel

Tags: java, security, applet, jnlp, controlpanel

Am using applet for file downloading. I need to uncheckable few options in "java control panel" for to hide the "security waring messages" in browser(this is one time activity).

But, Is there any possibility to hide the "security warning message" via java coding?

[image]

**Java Version:** 1.7.0.25

Thanks for looking into this..

Comment: Hm, you download a Applet from a server to download a file from a Server? Sounds like Eat against world hunger. 
Just an idea: Download the file directly :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any possibility to hide the "security warning message" via java coding?

No.  If there was, it would be a bug.  Depending on what warning is shown, it might be possible to stop it by digitally signing the code.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10405434/418556) describes one that cannot be changed.

[image]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12986334/418556) goes on to show how it looks when the certificate is generated by the developer.

---

> Java has discovered application components that could indicate a security concern. Contact the application vendor to ensure that it has not been tampered with.

..but that is a [mixed code warning](http://java.com/en/download/help/error_mixedcode.xml) produced by Java.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have created and singed a jar through net-beans editor. Browser throws the following security warning message. "Block potentially unsafe components from being run?". How to block the message through coding?

Comment: *"Browser throws the following.."  What browser specifically?

Comment: Am using google-chrome. While downloading, I saw that message. I think that message throws by java.

Comment: *"I think that message throws by java."*  Show me a screenshot.

Comment: Is it possible to automate this process?

Comment: What do you mean by 'automate'?  Did you follow the advice in the linked document?

Comment: *"how to handle this via coding.."*  If it could be done 'by coding' that would be a security bug!  Please let us know if you find a way, and we'll file a high priority bug report with Oracle.

Comment: Thank you Andrew. Am unable to chat. I have one more clarification. I think in "Java Control Panel" we need to set for ever user for one machine. Is it possible to set the setting in "java control panel" for all user(without the help of administrator)?

Comment: *"(without the help of administrator)?"*  Don't you think that might be a security bug as well?  For pity's sake, get it through your head.  These measures are there for the protection of the user.  There ***is no way around them.***  Also, ignore the *"Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?"* message.  It is the site, not me, inviting you to 'chat'.